# Cycle2 - SwipeUp

Tags: swipe, cycle

I really need some help with this if anyone out there cares to be my life saver! I am using Cycle2 to do a feature and I am trying to apply swipe for iPad and iPhone. I have tried TouchSwipe, Wipetouch and the debugged version of CycleSwipe.

Here is the problem, my slider is Vertical and I want a SwipeUp and SwipeDown commend. I have spent a whole working day trying to get this and I just cannot get it working! Can anyone tell me how I can get a SwipeUp and Swipe down command for Cycle2? Also is it possible for the movement to be a little smoother?
My feature is using full bleed images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about, but I think it works: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/swipe.php

By the way, you can use Hammer.js to capture swipe gestures: http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

Answer (score 0):

old question, but still.

I've made a patch a year ago to malsup's swipe plugin, that you can find here: https://github.com/walidvb/cycle2/commit/0c53a8972642ae90b865aae45d61f19aba807366#diff-0

That never made it to malsup's plugin unfortunately, but there you have it :)